# Android get current Arabic/Islamic date in English written format

Tags: android, date-format

I am facing problem to find current Islamic date, I have search from stackoverflow and found some solution but those are not the exact solution what I need. Here is my code which give me output as الأربعاء, أبريل ١٩, ٢٠١٧ but I want to show the date as "17th Jumada Al-Awwal 1438" format. the date should be written in English.

```
    Locale locale = new Locale("ar");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM dd, yyy", locale);
    Date currDate = new Date();
    String formattedDate = sdf.format(currDate);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that question about Hijri in java/android was already asked ... use search option

Comment: Does it work to use this constructor: `Locale (String language, 
                String country)`, so `Locale (Locale.ENGLISH, 
                "AE")` or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no built-in support for islamic calendar on Android unless you are willing to limit your app to [API-level 24](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/util/IslamicCalendar.html) (and if you like the old-fashioned API-style of ICU4J-class contributed by IBM ;-)). But maybe you can consider my library [Time4A](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4A) and then use this code (see also [javadoc](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/calendar/HijriCalendar.html)):

```
ChronoFormatter<HijriCalendar> hijriFormat =
    ChronoFormatter.setUp(HijriCalendar.family(), Locale.ENGLISH)
    .addEnglishOrdinal(HijriCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    .addPattern(" MMMM yyyy", PatternType.CLDR)
    .build()
    .withCalendarVariant(HijriCalendar.VARIANT_UMALQURA);

// conversion from gregorian to hijri-umalqura valid at noon 
// (not really valid in the evening when next islamic day starts)
HijriCalendar today = 
    SystemClock.inLocalView().today().transform(
        HijriCalendar.class,
        HijriCalendar.VARIANT_UMALQURA
    );
System.out.println(hijriFormat.format(today)); // 22nd Rajab 1438

// taking into account the specific start of day for Hijri calendar
HijriCalendar todayExact = 
    SystemClock.inLocalView().now(
        HijriCalendar.family(),
        HijriCalendar.VARIANT_UMALQURA,
        StartOfDay.EVENING // simple approximation => 18:00
    ).toDate();
System.out.println(hijriFormat.format(todayExact)); // 22nd Rajab 1438 (23rd after 18:00)
```

About the language support, all text resources are overtaken from CLDR-v30-data (Unicode-consortium). For example in English: "Jumada II" denotes the 6th month of the year. If you don't like it, you might also provide your own texts. The formatter-builder has a [dedicated method](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/format/expert/ChronoFormatter.Builder.html#addText-net.time4j.engine.ChronoElement-java.util.Map-) to do this.